# Clustering massive data sets in practice

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

If you have a very large data set of $n$ vectors and you want to cluster them according to some metric measure, what is the current state of the art when you can not afford to do more than $\Theta(n)$ work?  I am interested in methods that work well in practice as well as having nice theoretical properties.

A web search brings up "A sublinear time approximation scheme for clustering in metric spaces" by P. Indyk as the most cited paper in the area.

Comment: THere's also lots of work on sampling and streaming-based methods. These tend to work best when the metric is the Euclidean distance (or relatives). I'm not sure what your situation is.

Comment: @SureshVenkat Weighted Euclidean distance works for me.  I can find lists of papers, what I am not clear on is which are considered the current state of the art from an algorithms/practice point of view.

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of sounding immodest, I wrote a [short survey on stream clustering](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/web/2008/03/29/clustering-on-streams/) a few years ago. It's a little out of date, but not overly so, and doing forward citations will get you to the recent work in the area.

Comment: Thank you. I can see that people are very interested in streams. In my problem I have access to all the data, it is just very large.